# Skip animations on current slide in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

This is most likely a fairly simple question but I could not find any answers when I looked around (might be just me who is not really good at googling).

I have a fairly long powerpoint presentation where I use different sections, hyperlinks between them and animations on each slide (roughly 60 in total). Depending on the person I'm talking to I hide some slides while showing others. Sometimes when I skip to the next slide the person listening asks me to go back a few slides. The process of going back a few slides is not really difficult as you only press the left arrow key (or page up or whatever), but it doesn't look professional when you have to press it 6 times to go backwards (or forward) through the animations that many of the slides have.

Suppose that I am 2 animations in into a 7 animation slide and I want to directly skip ahead to the next slide; is there a way to, with one keyboard command, skip the remaining 5 animations on the current slide and go to the next one? I want to be able to continue through PPT slides without going through every single animation, on the fly (if this is possible).

Any answers to this is much appreciated!

Comment: is there at least any option to jump to next section with the keyboard?

Comment: I would love that too. I imagine you could create a 'next slide' button on every page with a hyperlink to 'Next Slide' and then use a PPT built-in shortcut to access that button, but then it only works on your computer... _IF_ that's possible :)

Comment: So annoying there'a no option for this. PgUp & PgDn buttons of keyboard would seem perfect candidate keys for such slide-jumps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

During a presentation, you can type the a slide number and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go directly to the specific slide. This may be the easiest way to skip the remaining animations on the current slide.

Here are useful [Keyboard shortcuts for use while delivering a presentation in PowerPoint 2013](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-use-while-delivering-a-presentation-in-powerpoint-2013-HA102749078.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102749080).

Comment: I guess I will have to remember where I have the important information :) OR, I could just add slide numbers in the bottom corner. Great tip, thank you!

Comment: There is no shortcut no jump to the next page without playing the animations

Comment: @skan We know that. What it the point of your comment?

Answer (score 7):

Often you have a standard box on every sheet, (logo, date, page#, etc, or you ca create one).
You can now right-mouse click this item and choose 'Action settings' then place a tick 'Hyperlink to' next slide  (or any other choice)

[image: Powerpoint Menu screenshot]

You can also build this in a master template: e.g. 3 buttons of your own design that go to: previous, next, or a preselected index page of your choice.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a great number of slides this may not work so well.
But if they are titled and easy to recognise you may be able to use the context menu for quicker access then skip back and forward.

Under the context submenu "Go to Slide" you will find the titles for your slides. Just click the one you want and it will go to that slide in its start form, first animation.
[image: PowerPoint in show context menu]

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but works better for a smaller presentation. I will keep this in mind though, thank you!