# How do I jump directly to next page without animations?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

If I have a PowerPoint document with several pages and several animations per page...

If I press the "Right Arrow" it will go to the next animation on the same page, and it will continue jumping to next animation till the last animation on that page. Only then PowerPoint will jump to the next page.

If I have too many animations it could be quite slow to cycle through pages.

Is there any way to jump directly to next page without pressing as many times as animations...  (in the reading View Mode).

If you want to go backwards instead is faster because it doesn't activate all the animations, it goes directly to the previous page.  How can I do it forward?

I know you can go directly to page number N if you type the number but you need to know it beforehand and this is a different story.

I'm interested in solutions for PowerPoint 2013 or 2016.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skip animations on current slide in PowerPoint](http://superuser.com/questions/680424/skip-animations-on-current-slide-in-powerpoint). BTW Did you try to press `H`? [Some shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-keyboard-shortcuts-to-deliver-your-presentation-1524ffce-bd2a-45f4-9a7f-f18b992b93a0?CTT=5&origin=HA102749080&CorrelationId=f7018b96-2d58-4981-85c8-af45b8660019&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Obviously it's not a duplicate.  I clearly stated I don't want to go to page number hat know you can go directly to page number N by typing it. That solution is not useful if you want to browse quickly the pages, you need to know the numertation beforehand.  Creating an action on every page is not a useful solution either.  I'm just asking for a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

One odd trick that might help:

Go into slide sorter view
Press CTRL+A to select all

(You may then need to CTRL+Click the first slide in the show ... test this)

Hide all of the slides.

Now in slide show view you can press H to advance to the next Hidden slide.
When I tested this, it ignored the animations and jumped directly to the next slide.

Comment: Good idea but a little bit strange. I would need to hide and unhide many times.

Comment: True, but it would only take a few seconds each time, a clear win over the time it would take to plow through lots of complex animations.  By the way, visit powerpoint.uservoice.com and enter the idea for a NEXT SLIDE keystroke combo as a feature request.  It's a very good idea.